# How to make getUsermedia work on instagram?

Tags: javascript, webview, instagram, instagram-api, getusermedia

I have a posted my website URL in instagram. The website needs camera access using getusermedia. When I click on the URL, it opens in instagram webview, it doesn't open camera. How can I make getusermedia work on instagram webview or How can make URL to open in the other browser like chrome or safari?

https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/
This also doesn't work in instagram and facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

getUserMedia doesn't work correctly on embedded browsers in mobile devices, sad to say.  And it works somewhat inconsistently in those devices' native browsers.

Also, app publishers like Instagram may consider this to be a security feature, to protect their users from being spied upon.

Plus, app publishers do whatever they can to keep users in their app, rather than out to a browser.

See this. https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream